# ¿Cómo puedo establecer elementos desde el teclado en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array

¡Hola!
Tengo que crear una función que, secuencialmente, me permita introducir los datos de los nuevos alumnos utilizando un prompt para cada dato. Después, tengo que asignar un departamento a cada uno de estos alumnos. Mi código es el siguiente.

```
var alumno= {
    nombre: undefined,
    apellidos: undefined,
    genero: undefined,
    materias: undefined,
    departamento: undefined
}; 
var departamentos = [ matematicas, fisica, linguistica];
var alumnos= new Array();
mensaje="Introducir nuevo alumno";
            prompt(departamentos.alumno.nombre);
            prompt (departamento.alumno.apellidos);
            prompt (departamento.alumno.genero);
            prompt (departamento.alumno.materias);
            prompt (departamento.alumno.departamento);

indiceDepartamento=0;
            departamentos.alumnos.forEach (
            function (departamentoActual) {
                indiceDepartamento++
                console.log(indiceDepartamento + ": " + this.nombre);
                var indiceAlumno = 0;
                departamentoActual.alumno.forEach (
                function(alumnoNuevo) {
                    indiceTrabajador++
                    if (alumnoNuevo!=undefined) {
                        console.log(" " + indiceDepartamento + "." + indiceAlumno + "- " + alumnoNuevo.nombre);
                    } else {
                        console.log(" " + indiceDepartamento + "." + indiceAlumno + "- " + "No existe");
                    }
                }
            );
            }
            )
```

Lo estoy probando en la consola de Firefox y me sale el error "departamentos.alumnos is undefined", pero no lo termino de ver. ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano, por favor?

Comment: Osea tienes que poder crear un alumno y ademas a ese alumno poder asignarle un departamento verdad? No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres decir.

Comment: Sí, eso es. Tengo que introducir los datos de nuevos alumnos utilizando prompt() y después, asignarle un departamento.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, si entendi lo que tu necesitas hacer, para explicar el error vamos a ir por partes.

Cada alumno es un objeto que cuenta con distintos atributos, entre ellos el departamento al que pertenece.

```
var alumno= {
 nombre: undefined,
 apellidos: undefined,
 genero: undefined,
 materias: undefined,
 departamento: undefined
};
```

Tu tienes un array de departamentos que solo cuenta con tres valores.

```
var departamentos = [ matematicas, fisica, linguistica];
```

A partir de este punto y teniendo en cuenta que lo que tienes que hacer es asignar un departamento a cada uno de estos alumnos creo que estas confundiendo conceptualmente lo que significa asignarle un departamento a un alumno.

Por un lado estas considerando que cada alumno tiene una propiedad "departamento" y a su vez (en base al resto del codigo) que cada departamento tiene un conjunto de alumnos que pertenecen a ese departamento.Esto se refleja en la linea 15:

```
prompt (departamento.alumno.departamento);
```

Ya que no puedes referenciar a un alumno especifico dentro de un departamento que no tiene referencia a ningun conjunto de alumnos, de hecho ni siquiera hay ningun objeto "departamento" definido.

Tienes que optar por una solucion o la otra. Si decides que simplemente cada alumno tenga un atributo departamento en el prompt solo deberias ingresar la posicion en el array de el nombre de ese atributo que le quieres asignar.

Ahora si decides que cada departamento tenga un conjunto de alumnos (como al parecer lo habias interpretado) entonces, deberias borrar el atributo departamento del alumno y definir el objeto Departamento, donde cada departamento tenga como propiedades el conjunto de alumnos y el nombre de ese departamento.Y luego esos objetos serian guardados en un arreglo de "Departamentos".

edit:

Como decidiste elegir la segunda opción lo que tendrias que hacer (viendo el codigo que actualizaste) seria coregir varios puntos.

Este seria el codigo que se me ocurre a mi, podria resolver tu problema de no poder cargar un alumno:

```
var matematicas = {
    nombre: "Matemáticas",
    presupuesto: 150000,
    jefeDepartamento: undefined,
    temas: undefined,
    alumnos: new Array(),
  };
  var fisica = {
    nombre: "Física",
    presupuesto: 250000,
    jefeDepartamento: undefined,
    temas: undefined,
    alumnos: new Array(),
  };
  var linguistica = {
    nombre: "Lingüística",
    presupuesto: 100000,
    jefeDepartamento: undefined,
    temas: undefined,
    alumnos: new Array(),
  };

  var departamentos = [matematicas, fisica, linguistica];

  //Defino los datos del alumno.
  var alumno = {
    nombre: undefined,
    apellidos: undefined,
    genero: undefined,
    materias: undefined,
    departamentos: undefined,
  };

  //Ingreso los datos del alumno.
  alumno.nombre = prompt("Ingrese el nombre del alumno.");
  alumno.apellidos = prompt("Ingrese los apellidos del alumno.");
  alumno.genero = prompt("Ingrese el genero del alumno.");
  alumno.materias = prompt("Ingrese las materias del alumno.");

  //Solicito el departamento del alumno y verifico el dato obtenido.
  let opcion = prompt("Ingrese el departamento del alumno:");
  let departamentoSeleccionado;
  switch (opcion) {
    case "Matematica":
      departamentoSeleccionado = departamentos[0];
      break;
    case "Fisica":
      departamentoSeleccionado = departamentos[1];
      break;
    case "Linguistica":
      departamentoSeleccionado = departamentos[2];
      break;
    default:
      alert("El departamento elegido no es valido.");
      break;
  }
//Coloco el alumno ingresado en el arreglo de los alumnos del departamento.
  departamentoSeleccionado.alumnos.push(alumno);
```

Pero vamos a analizar por partes lo que tu hiciste para que te quede claro.

Primero:

```
var alumnos = {
    nombre: undefined,
    apellidos: undefined,
    genero: undefined,
    materias: undefined,
departamentos: undefined
};

var alumnos = new Array();
```

Aqui simplemente cometiste el error de quitar la referencia de la variable alumnos al hacer que referencie a un arreglo.

Simplemente deberias llamar a la primer variable alumno.

De todas maneras creo que no es necesario tener un arreglo de alumnos definido y por eso no lo coloque en mi solucion de ejemplo.

Segundo:

```
prompt(departamentos.alumnos.nombre);
prompt(departamentos.alumnos.apellidos);                    
prompt(departamentos.alumnos.genero);           
prompt(departamentos.alumnos.materias);
prompt(departamentos.alumnos.departamento);
```

Aqui el error que estas cometiendo es un poco complejo.

Primero: las variables "departamentos" y "alumnos" son arreglos de objetos y por lo tanto para poder acceder a un valor en especifico tienes que darle una posicion(por ejemplo: departamentos[0], alumnos[2]).

Segundo: lo que estas pasandole como parametro al metodo prompt es el mensaje que va a aparecer en el navegador no lo que estas asignandole al objeto.

Comment: Primero, ¡muchísimas gracias por la explicación! Soy nueva en esto y estoy un poco (bastante) perdida. Mi intención era hacerlo como dices en el último párrafo, voy a probar así, pero ¡mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

He corregido el código definiendo cada uno de los departamentos e introduciendo dentro de ellos a los alumnos (cuyos datos obtendremos a partir de lo que introduzcamos en el prompt). Me sigue pasando lo mismo, creo que no termino de entenderlo. 
Reformulo mi problema. Hay 3 departamentos en una universidad (matematicas, física y linguistica) con ciertos parámetros (nombre, presupuesto, jefe de departamento y temas). Estos 3 departamentos los he incluido en un array "Departamentos". 
Inicialmente, no tengo ningún alumno guardado, los tengo que introducir a través del teclado. Para cada alumno, necesito introducir nombre, apellidos, genero, materias y departamento de los anteriores al que pertenece. Esos alumnos se guardarán en un array nuevo con el nombre "Alumnos" que he dejado vacío para almacenar ahí los nuevos datos.
Sin embargo, al ejecutar, sigo teniendo el mismo problema, me dice que departamentos.alumnos no está definido.

```
var matematicas = { 
    nombre: "Matemáticas", 
    presupuesto: 150000,
    jefeDepartamento: undefined,
    temas: undefined,
    alumnos: new Array()
};
var fisica = { 
    nombre: "Física", 
    presupuesto: 250000,
    jefeDepartamento: undefined,
    temas: undefined,
    alumnos: new Array()
}; 
var linguistica = { 
    nombre: "Lingüística", 
    presupuesto: 100000,
    jefeDepartamento: undefined,
    temas: undefined,
    alumnos: new Array()
};

var alumnos = {
    nombre: undefined,
    apellidos: undefined,
    genero: undefined,
    materias: undefined,
departamentos: undefined
};

var departamentos = [ matematicas, fisica, linguistica];

var alumnos = new Array();

mensaje="Introducir nuevo alumno";           
            indiceDepartamento=0;
            departamentos.alumnos.forEach (
            function (departamentoActual) {
                indiceDepartamento++;
                console.log(indiceDepartamento + ": " + this.nombre);
                var indiceAlumno = 0;
                departamentoActual.alumno.forEach (
                function(trabajadorActual) {
                    indiceAlumno++;
                    if (alumnoActual!=undefined) {
                        console.log(" " + indiceDepartamento + "." + indiceAlumno + "- " + alumnoActual.nombre);
                    } else {
                        console.log(" " + indiceDepartamento + "." + indiceAlumno + "- " + "No existe el alumno");
                    }
                }
            );
            }
            )
            prompt(departamentos.alumnos.nombre);
            prompt(departamentos.alumnos.apellidos);                    
            prompt(departamentos.alumnos.genero);           
            prompt(departamentos.alumnos.materias);
            prompt(departamentos.alumnos.departamento);
```

¿Quizás tendría que añadir un array departamentos.alumnos = []; que se fuese llenando con los datos introducidos?
¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Esta es la solución a tu pregunta?, de no ser así debe entonces ir como edición a tu pregunta